# Program wont stop stacking memory

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I wrote a program that displays live images from a sensor. The problem is that it keeps eating up the memory.

```
        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object bpic = cam.GrabFrame();
            uint[] pic = cam.ColorPipe(bpic, out width, out height, out bitdepth);
            byte[] header = GetHeader.BuildHeader(width, height, bitdepth);
            byte[] img = GetHeader.UintImageToByte(pic, width, height, bitdepth);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            GC.Collect();
            ms.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
            ms.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Dispose();
        }
    }
    class GetHeader
    {
        #region Image
        public static byte[] UintImageToByte(uint[] img, uint nWidth, uint nHeight, uint nBitsPerPixel)
        {
            int nBytesPerPixel = (int)nBitsPerPixel / 8;
            byte[] AoB = new byte[nWidth * nHeight * nBytesPerPixel];
            int j = 0;
            byte[] pixel;
            // Get each uint value from image and convert it to bytes
            for (int i = 0; i < img.Length; i++)
            {
                pixel = BitConverter.GetBytes(img[i]);
                // Add each pixel bytes to the image array
                for (int k = nBytesPerPixel - 1; k >= 0; k--)
                {
                    AoB[j++] = pixel[k];
                }
            }
            byte temp;
            // Swap the elements to create a true color image
            for (int i = 0; i < AoB.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                temp = AoB[i];
                AoB[i] = AoB[AoB.Length - 1 - i];
                AoB[AoB.Length - 1 - i] = temp;
            }
            return AoB;
        }
        #endregion
        #region Header
        /* IMPORTANT!!!!!
         * All numerical values are little endian!
         * 4660 in decimal will be 3421 in hex not 1234!
         * IMPORTANT!!!!! */
        private const uint HEADER_SIZE = 54;
        private const string FOUR_BYTE_ZERO = "00000000";
        private const string TWO_BYTE_ZERO = "0000";
        private const string BM = "424D";
        public static byte[] BuildHeader(uint nWidth, uint nHeight, uint nBitsPerPixel)
        {
            // Substring is to get the amount of bytes needed.
            // BitConverter currently returns 4 bytes and in case it will change
            // the substring will take the amount of bytes it needs.
            string sWidth = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(nWidth)).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 8);
            string sHeight = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(nHeight)).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 8);
            string sBitsPerPixel = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(nBitsPerPixel)).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 4);
            uint nImageSize = ((nWidth * nHeight) * (nBitsPerPixel / 8));
            string sFileSize = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(nImageSize + HEADER_SIZE)).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 8);
            string sImageSize = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(nImageSize)).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 8);
            string sHeader = String.Empty;

            sHeader += BM;              // 0h  | File tpye          | 2 bytes
            sHeader += sFileSize;       // 2h  | File size          | 4 bytes
            sHeader += TWO_BYTE_ZERO;   // 6h  | N/A                | 2 bytes
            sHeader += TWO_BYTE_ZERO;   // 8h  | N/A                | 2 bytes
            sHeader += "36000000";      // Ah  | Data offset        | 4 bytes
            sHeader += "28000000";      // Eh  | DIB Size           | 4 bytes
            sHeader += sWidth;          // 12h | Width              | 4 bytes
            sHeader += sHeight;         // 16h | Height             | 4 bytes
            sHeader += "0100";          // 1Ah | Color planes       | 2 bytes
            sHeader += sBitsPerPixel;   // 1Ch | Bits per pixel     | 2 bytes
            sHeader += FOUR_BYTE_ZERO;  // 1Eh | Compression        | 4 bytes
            sHeader += sImageSize;      // 22h | Image size         | 4 bytes
            sHeader += FOUR_BYTE_ZERO;  // 26h | Horizontal res     | 4 bytes
            sHeader += FOUR_BYTE_ZERO;  // 2Ah | Vertical res       | 4 bytes
            sHeader += FOUR_BYTE_ZERO;  // 2Eh | Color pallete      | 4 bytes
            sHeader += FOUR_BYTE_ZERO;  // 32h | Important colors   | 4 bytes

            byte[] Header = StringToAoB(sHeader);

            return Header;
        }
        private static byte[] StringToAoB(string str)
        {
            byte[] AoB = new byte[str.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < AoB.Length; i++, j += 2)
            {
                AoB[i] = byte.Parse(HexToInt("0x" + str[j] + str[j + 1]).ToString());
            }
            return AoB;
        }
        private static int HexToInt(string Hex)
        {
            Hex = Hex.Replace("0x", "");
            return Int32.Parse(Hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        }
        #endregion
```

The critical functions are `tmr_Tick` and `UintImageToByte`.
`cam.GrabFrame()` returns a single dimension array containing raw image data.
`cam.ColorPipe()` arranges it to contain `uint` representation of each pixel in a single dimension array.

I have no idea on where the problem seems to be, if its memory is not getting cleaned off the memory stream or maybe the interval is too fast (200 ms) for the gc to tag unused memory and clean it up.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone would take some time to look at the code and give some pointers on how it may be fixed.
I've tried `using (MemoryStream ms....)` block, to no avail.
The `ms.Flush()`, `ms.Dispose()` and `GC.Collect()` are attempts to try and get rid of the used memory, still no go.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your MemoryStream in a ``using`` block?

Comment: Do you actually get an out-of-memory-exception? C# garbage collection does not work like destructors in C++, the garbage collector can decide that collecting is not yet neccessary. If you have a lot of RAM and no other programs requesting memory, it may well decide that garbage collection can wait until there is no more free memory.

Comment: @MathewCollins, yes. "I've tried using (MemoryStream ms....) block, to no avail."

Comment: @nvoigt, Yes. After a couple of minutes I get oom exception. I tested it on a PC with 32GB of RAM and once it reached about ~1.5GB it raised the error.

Comment: Does `cam` implement IDisposable? Given that it talks to a hardware device I wouldn't be surprised if it did. In which case you need to dispose of it.

Comment: @JackHughes It does, but when you access it every 200 ms, disposing it  and re-accessing it every time will be pretty much a huge waste of time, Time complexity-wise.

Comment: As we don't have the hardware or full code, you will have to test it yourself: comment out all in your timer. Test it. If it throws no exception after a while, put in line after line, testing it again. If it crashes, the last line you put back in is your culprit.

Comment: As a sidenote: I don't see any timer controlling code in your timer function. How do you make sure your timer is not called again if it does not finish inside the timers interval?

Comment: What about `bpic` does that implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: @nvoigt commenting any line before the pictureBox1 line will cause an exception in the pictureBox1 line, since the image will be invalid.
I did not enter any error checks or precautions, since this is not close to be a final product. However, I did not account that it may cause large memory usage. I'll add a check for it now.

Comment: @JackHughes, No. bpic contains a single dimensional array, returned from cam.GrabFrame().

Comment: Do you have the source for `cam` object? The memory leak may well be in there.

Comment: @JackHughes, Afraid not. It is a DLL provided by Aptina Imaging. I also highly doubt there is a leak in their code.